# Android -Draw a view on canvas

Tags: java, android, c++, android-canvas

i have try to draw a finger paint in android using Canvas. I have used the paint for Coloring the Current path.Remove and Appear the paths using undo redo option.But undo Redo works well. i use the Red color for Paint if i use the another color for drawing all the previous paths are changed to current color.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class CustomView extends View implements OnTouchListener {
    public Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    public Paint mPaint, mBitmapPaint;
    Bitmap mBitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    TabletActivity tabletActivity;
    public ArrayList<Path> paths = new ArrayList<Path>();
    public ArrayList<Path> undonePaths = new ArrayList<Path>();

    private Bitmap im;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mPath = new Path();

        im = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                          R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext()
                                    .getResources()
                                    .getDisplayMetrics();
        int w = metrics.widthPixels;
        int h = metrics.heightPixels;
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        // mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC))
        // ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // mPath = new Path();
        // canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
        for (Path p : paths) {
            canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        undonePaths.clear();
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        paths.add(mPath);
        mPath = new Path();
    }

    public void onClickUndo() {
        if (paths.size() > 0) {
            undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
    // toast the user
    }

    public void onClickRedo() {
        if (undonePaths.size() > 0) {
            paths.add(undonePaths.remove(undonePaths.size() - 1));
            invalidate();
        } else {

        }
        // toast the user
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touch_start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touch_move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touch_up();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As user603125 says, currently you only have one paint object and you paint all paths with that  paint. Remember that in onDraw you draw *all* paths anew every time.
To solve this, you'll have to keep track of the color to use by every path, e.g. in a map and do something like so:

```
private Map<Path, Color> mPathColors = new HashMap<Path, Color>(); // map for path colors
private Color mCurrentColor; // color to paint current path with (has to be set somewhere)
...
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    for (Path p : paths) {
        mPaint.setColor(mPathColors.get(p);
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }
    mPaint.setColor(mCurrentColor);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

And in `touch_up()` write the current color to the map like so:

```
private void touch_up() {
   ...
   paths.add(mPath);
   mPathColors.put(mPath, mCurrentColor);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the Same paint object to draw the previous and as well as the current path.

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
    for (Path p : paths) {
        canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    }
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```